# Solid validation in c#

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I want to implement a validation pattern for BLL classes in c# .netcore2.2 .
any idea can be helpful

I have many classes as service in BLL, I want to set validation rule from out of class.

```
public class TerminalService
{
    private readonly IRepository<TerminalLog> _terminalRepository;
    private readonly IRepository<PutLog> _logger;

    public TerminalService(IRepository<PutLog> logger, IRepository<TerminalLog> terminalRepository)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _terminalRepository = terminalRepository;

    }


    public async Task<BaseResult<List<TerminalLog>>> GetTerminals(BaseInput<TerminalInput> input)
    {
        BaseResult<List<TerminalLog>> result = new BaseResult<List<TerminalLog>>();

        try
        {
           //check validation
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Add(new PutLog { DateTime = DateTime.Now, Module = "BillPayment-Validate", Message = ex.Message, Title = "ValidateError", Info = input.ToString() });
            result.Meta.Message = ex.Message;
            return result;
        }


        result.Data =  _terminalRepository.Find(a => a.IsActive && a.Type == input.Value.Type).OrderBy(a=>a.Order).ToList();
        result.Meta.Code = 0;
        result.Meta.Resp = "0";
        result.Meta.Message = "ok";

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The most common pattern is to use the `if` construct. Were you thinking of something specific?

Comment: You should consider implementing validation with c# attributes. This is called Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP). Look at http://www.jot.fm/issues/issue_2007_03/article1/ for more information. That way you implement validation on separated classes.

Comment: https://fluentvalidation.net/

Comment: i think maybe AOP with attr, not good idea for unit testing